# Can not access element attributes after passing the reference jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML grid which has variable number of rows which has a datepicker in first column & an HTML button in 3rd column.

I need to get the reference of button & pass it around in functions(may be more then once) to call its click or access its attribute at various places.

```
var myButton = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=button]'); // accesing the button in a function
```

further I am passing this variable in an object to another JS function doSomething

```
doSomething.call(this, { 'btnRef': myButton[0] }, condition);
```

Inside the doSmething function I am saving this reference in a global JS object

```
unsavedObj['btnRef'] = arguments[0]['btnRef']; // I also tried jQuery(arguments[0]['btnRef'])
```

Problem occurs after I try to access an attribute via the global object

```
unsavedObj['btnRef'].attr('rel')
unsavedObj['btnRef'] // shows as undefined in console.
```

I can access attributes etc correctly inside the function where var myButton is getting the value also `jQuery(arguments[0]['btnRef'].attr('rel'))` returns the right result as well.
  Is this the problem due to context?.

Sample code:

```
//this is the datepicker handler which fires on select of a date.


    onSelect: function(d,i) {
                    var condition  = false;
                        var myButton  = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=button]');                  
                        var btnRel    = myButton.attr('rel'); 
                    //some other vars

                    myButton.prop("disabled", false); //this works fine

                    if(jQuery(myButton).hasClass('xyz')){       
                       if(changedFor !=''){                      
                          if(changedFor == btnRel){ 
                            condition = (changedFor == btnRel); 
                          }
                        }             
                        doSomething.call(this,{'btnRef':myButton},condition);//passing to the function doSomething
                    }         
                    }


//doSomething function.
function doSomething(){           
                    var thisObj = jQuery(this)             
                    if(arguments[1]){
                          unsavedObj['btnRef'].triggerHandler('click',{'check':arguments[1]});           
                    }else{
                          BootstrapDialog.show({ //this is a bootstrap dialogbox
                                title:'',
                                  message:function(dialog){
                                          var $content = "Are you sure?";
                                                return '<div>' + $content + '</div>';
                                      },
                                  closable: false,
                                  buttons: [{
                                        label:'Change',
                                        cssClass: 'btn',
                                        action: function(dialogItself){
                                          unsavedObj['btnRef']   = arguments[0]['btnRef'];   
                                          unsavedObj['context']  = thisObj; 
                                          changedFor                 = unsavedObj['btnRef'].attr('rel'); //does not work    
                                          unsavedObj['btnRef'].click();     //does not work          
                                                dialogItself.close();
                                      }
                                     },{
                                      label:'Cancel',
                                      cssClass:'btn',
                                      action: function(dialogItself){
                                          dialogItself.close();
                                      }
                                  }]
                                });
                    }
            }
```

Im sorry for the poor formatting.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you mixing pure javascript and jQuery? Once, you started to use jQuery, use it to get rid off headaches.

Comment: Can you please provide full **sample** code?

Comment: Does this solve the problem: `$(unsavedObj['btnRef']).attr('rel')`
I believe that when you use `myButton[0]`,  it's no longer a jQuery object so you can't use `.attr` later on. You need to reconvert it to a jQuery Object. But in my opinion, what you're doing, could be simplified a lot if you posted more code.

Comment: When you do myButton[0] you are getting an html object, not a jQuery object.  Then when you try to do unsavedObj['btnRef'].attr('rel') it wont work because it is not a jQuery object.

Comment: Does the function make an AJAX call?

Comment: @PeterKA no but there is a BootStrap Dialog box involved.

Comment: @vyx.ca I thought the same but how come `myButton.attr('rel')` works?

Comment: @lolka_bolka can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: @techie_28  What do you think myButton.attr('rel') is supposed to do?

Comment: @nurdyguy it gives back the rel attribute of the button.

Comment: Can you post some of the html also?

Comment: this appears to be problem of `closures`.I can access them correctly outside `BootstrapDialog.show({...` but not inside its `buttons: [...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this problem was happening due to the limitation of closures to access the `arguments` object of outer function & here `Bootstrap.show({..'s` button definition was actually a closure.
It was resolved by creating a copy of `arguments`.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 var myButton = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=button]');
```

to

```
 var myButton = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=button]');
```

then change

```
 doSomething.call(this, { 'btnRef': myButton[0] }, condition);
```

to

```
 doSomething.call(this, { 'btnRef': myButton }, condition);
```

Now you are creating an array of jQuery objects rather than an array of html objects so the .attr(...) function should work.

EDIT:
I suspect there are multiple issues at work here.  Since you said the above didn't work, lets take a look at doSomething.call(...).  Look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call for the documentation.  Note that the this there is not a jQueryable $(this) but a reference to the arguments you passed in the calling statement.

Question 1:  Is doSomething being called anywhere else?  If not then lets build out the signature a little bit more explicitly and just call it using a more conventional function call:

```
function doSomething(varA, varB, ...){   }
```

and

```
doSomething(....actual passed variables...)
```

Lets start there and see how we do.

Comment: If HTML objects then wrapping it with `jQuery` should have worked?

Comment: You can do that if you turn it back into jQuery using $(htmlObj).

Comment: Sorry, had to run to a meeting and couldn't finish my thought...  You can turn the html object back in to a jQuery object, but keep in mind that doing so means you are reparsing the DOM.  Why do that when you can just save it as jQuery to begin with?  Unless there is a specific reason to want the html object, leave it as a jQuery object.

Comment: this was my first thought but It did not help.

Comment: I reread part of the post and it kind of sounds like a scope problem.  arguments is a global variable right?  What about unsavedObj?

Comment: arguments is the local var which JS makes for every function,UnSavedObj is a global object.

Comment: Yes you are right this is a scope problem as I can access it outside the `Bootstrap.show({..`